# Canvas repeat rect

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to make kind of a pattern for my background, but I want to draw the rectangle myself, not use an image.

CODE:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="33" height="33"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(0, 0, 32, 32);
  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = 'silver';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

So far it creates the rectangle that I want. Now I want to repeat it in X and Y.

Furthermore, is this a viable way of doing this if I want to add a mouseOnHover animation to each square(same animation) later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can create a grid of mouse-over-able rectangles:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    cw = 32,
    ch = 32,
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height;

ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
ctx.beginPath(); // not neede here, but if in a larger project

for(var y = 0; y < h; y += ch) {
 for(var x = 0; x < w; x += cw) {
      ctx.rect(x, y, cw-2, ch-2); // give 1px space  
  } 
}

ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";

ctx.lineWidth=1;
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      y = e.clientY - rect.top,
      cx = ((x / cw)|0) * cw,  //quantize mouse pos to grid
      cy = ((y / ch)|0) * ch;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(cx+1, cy+1, cw-3, ch-3);
};
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=320 height=320></canvas>
```

You should be able to adopt the principles shown to your need. Hope this helps!